# Java split TargetDataLine into notes

Tags: java, audio, visualization

I'm trying to make a graphic visualizer in Java, (yes I know they already exist. I want to make my own), and I have a mostly functional prototype right now, but my only problem is that it's displaying things weirdly. The source code is on my GitHub (thislooksfun/SoundReader), and [here](http://youtu.be/h_y5nRBTBFA) is a video of what it's doing. In comparison, [this](http://youtu.be/cUy78QHeuvs) is roughly what I'm trying to do (see the visualizer in the middle).
Any idea how to make this work?

Thanks in advance,
-tlf

Comment: Looks like you have a bug in your transform.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Just the way the data looks in your output. It looks like you have an off-by-1 error or something in your transform. Impossible to say exactly but that is what it looks like.

Comment: Actually I looked through your code and I don't see you doing a transform. Maybe I just missed it, else I've misunderstood. What is the graphic supposed to be?

Comment: Whoops. I put the wrong link in... Should be fixed. It's the last one.

Comment: Ok, I tweaked the code some, and now I get this: http://youtu.be/bmYAT4TT51I  
It looks cool, but I want to separate the different notes. So the left side would be low and the right would be high. Any idea how to do that? Not the rendering part, just the splitting.